# symfony2 and snc-redis: how to disable it depending of environement?

Tags: php, symfony, redis

I'm using snc-redis to cache my doctrine queries and everything works well.

As I'm working on a team, I decided to put the redis server on a remote machine but it encounters an error on connection "Error while writing bytes to the server [tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6379"

So I'm considering to deploy redis only for the production server and disable it for our development. The problem is for each repository we use predis query caching functions which lead to issues because no redis service is available.

Here is my configuration:

```
snc_redis:
# configure predis as client
clients:
    default:
        type: predis
        alias: default
        dsn: "redis://%redis_url%"
    doctrine:
        type: predis
        alias: doctrine
        dsn: "redis://%redis_url%"
# configure doctrine caching
doctrine:
    metadata_cache:
        client: doctrine
        entity_manager: default
        document_manager: default
    result_cache:
        client: doctrine
        entity_manager: [default]
        namespace: "doctrine_result_cache_%kernel.environment%_"
    query_cache:
        client: doctrine
        entity_manager: default
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a different configuration depending of environment with specific files in your config folder.

If put redis configuration in config_prod.yml instead config.yml, only works in prod environment.

Also you could create another file called for example config_yourenv.yml and load it from a distinct front controller.

In app.php:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
//require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

// Change the environment you load if want.
$kernel = new AppKernel('yourenv', false);
```

If you want exclude the whole load of the bundle, add this on AppKernel.php:

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('yourenv')) {
    $bundles[] = new Path\To\SncRedisBundle();
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: how about the predis query cache call inside repositories ?

Comment: If you use redis in your repositories, you must have a redis server. I suppose maybe in test environment you could install a local server instead a remote and maintain separated configurations.

Comment: Or maybe a try catch to check if redis server is available.

Comment: we are using a remote redis server and no local instance . try / catch could be a hook but that's not really clean code

Comment: I agree, but i think there isn't a way to simulate a redis server... So, i think that you need to install one or not use it at all when is not present. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I usually enable any kind of caching only for the `prod` environment. So i suggest you to leave the config.yml without any specific conf, only a basic definition for the snc_redis bundle.

As Example:

**config.yml**

```
snc_redis:
# configure predis as client
clients:
    default:
        type: predis
        alias: default
        dsn: "redis://%redis_url%"

# Standard Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
```

**config_prod.yml**

```
snc_redis:
# configure predis as client
clients:
    default:
        type: predis
        alias: default
        dsn: "redis://%redis_url%"
    doctrine:
        type: predis
        alias: doctrine
        dsn: "redis://%redis_url%"
# configure doctrine caching
doctrine:
    metadata_cache:
        client: doctrine
        entity_manager: default
        document_manager: default
    result_cache:
        client: doctrine
        entity_manager: [default]
        namespace: "doctrine_result_cache_%kernel.environment%_"
    query_cache:
        client: doctrine
        entity_manager: default
```

Hope this help